# ASP.net Mvc with multiple database connections

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How can I access multiple databases in a single project for inserting data at the same time? Is it possible to use different connection strings in a single `web.config` file?

Comment: just put new connection string with different name and map with your new DB

Comment: Yes, it is possible You can use your custom implementation to connect to SQL Server and control which connection string to use.

Comment: for Debug and Release?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.Use connectionStrings section in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connection1" connectionString="Your Connection string" providerName="Your provider name"/>
  <add name="connection2" connectionString="Your Connection string" providerName="Your provider name"/>
  <add name="connection3" connectionString="Your Connection string" providerName="Your provider name"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

use this connection string in your project as

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your connection string name"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

By adding many connection strings in your web.config file

As:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connection1" connectionString="First Connection string" providerName="Your provider name"/>
  <add name="connection2" connectionString="Second Connection string" providerName="Your provider name"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

and in your code, you can call wich connection String you want as:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["First Connection string"].ToString()
```

or

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Second Connection string"].ToString()
```